# how to open a pdf link in Web view and print this document to a printer without saving to device

Tags: android, pdf, webview

Link -https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf

I want to open a pdf link in webview and want to print that document to a printer without saving it into my device.

How can I do that in android????

Comment: It is unclear to me what should happen if you talk about 'open a pdf link in webview'. A WebView cannot display a pdf document to begin with.

Comment: For displaying the PDF, the LEADTOOLS [Android SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/android) and [JavaScript SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/javascript) have a native and web viewer control, respectively, that can be configured to encapsulate and render a PDF from a URI without downloading it to the device’s external storage. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the toolkit)